# Recover corrupted SD card

Tags: android, format, recovery

A friend of mine gave me a corrupted SD card. My windows 10 cannot detect it and on android it asks to format the corrupted SD card. Is there a way to partially or, best case, fully recover the data on this card?

Kind regards
Kurt

Comment: This isn't strictly a programming issue, so you may get better results asking on a site like Stack Overflow's sister site [Super User](https://superuser.com).

Comment: thx for the advice, I'll try my luck there ;) @dgnuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing you need to determine is if it's detected with correct capacity in disk management:

[This is what to look for in Disk Management](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LvKAZ.png)

If not then this is probably not DIY-able. A data recovery lab still could get the data by scraping off the back layer and soldering wires to a special reader.

If it is detected, my advise would be to create a sector by sector image file. Then, any decent file recovery software should be able to scan that image file as if it were a regular drive and recover the data.

To create such an image in Windows you could use [Win32 Disk Imager](https://sourceforge.net/projects/win32diskimager/), in Linux ddrescue. Any decent file recovery tool would allow you to create a drive image too.

I'll mention DMDE as an example as it is also a very good tool to analyze the image file with and recovers upto 4000 files for free (as long as they're in the same folder).